# Use CORS block port

Tags: http, cors, xmlhttprequest

Good morning people!

I am having CORS problem my application runs in apache but the service comes straight WS,
I already made the apache settings in the .xml file, but without success, there are some
way to solve! thank you

> msg error
>
> Access to fetch at ':9084/ApiSise/api/v1/projeto/form-result' from
>   origin ':8080' has  been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set  the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified</param-value>
</init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

/*index.html*/


  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <header name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value = "*" />
```

Comment: Which changes have you made? Any that relate to the given error message?

Comment: I already configured apache web.xml, but without success, WS already I did not configure anything.

Comment: And you don't want to share whatever you've tried, along with whatever code that is causing the problem?

Comment: ok..Look please, only configurated in apache.